# Upper bound of the k-th derivative of $g(t) = e^{-t^{-a}}$

Tags: derivatives

This is part of Stein and Shakarchi's *Fourier Analysis*, Chapter 5, Problem 4.

For $a > 0$, consider the function deﬁned by $$g(t) = \begin{cases}
    e^{-t^{-a}} & \text{if } t > 0\\
    0           & \text{if } t \leq 0.
\end{cases}$$

One can show that there exists $0 < \theta < 1$ depending on $a$ so that

$$| g^{(k)} (t) | \leq \frac{k!}{(\theta t)^k} e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^{−a}}$$

for $t > 0$.

I cannot figure out to do it.

Comment: Have you tried induction.

Comment: Fourier analysis, so the Cauchy integral formula isn't allowed?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes. That was the first thing that I tried. I wanted to get some kind of recursive formula for $g^{(k)}$ It got too complicated so I gave up.

Comment: @reuns Correct.